# not binding properties from propertyGrid to customUserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

In application I'm working on, there are userControls and a propertyGrid to show some properties. When properties are loaded and I change their value in propertyGrid, I can see that userControl is also updating.  There is a feature to undo changes. For that when user chooses to edit userControl, I create a deepCopy of userControl and keep working with original object. When user selects Undo changes, I set a copy to my original object:

```
var control = temp.ViewModel.AllControls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ViewModel.IsSelected); //finds selected userControl
if (control == null) return;

var t = (ISelectableViewModel)_copySelectedObject;
control.ViewModel = t; // set old values to userControl           
SelectedObject = control.ViewModel; // load properties in propertyGrid
```

The problem is that my userControl is not updated with new values after undo button is clicked, (only if I write in code control.ViewModel.Name = t.Name and so on). Also I have a problem with propertyGrid. It loads right values, but when I change property, it does not affect to my userControl. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Have you implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your `ViewModel` property?

Comment: @Sheridan yes. I fixed it already by resetting userControls datacontext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've solved it. For this I changed datacontext of my userControl, to a copy of the userControl. Hope this will help to somebody in the future.

Comment: What do you mean by `Copy of UserControl`?

Comment: @RohitVats I mean by copy of UserControl a deepCopy of UserControl that I made before editing UserControl properties.